# How do I configure Dropbox in my Galaxy S III so that it does NOT automatically upload every photo/video I take?

Tags: dropbox

How do I configure Dropbox on my mobile - Galaxy S III so that it does **not** automatically upload every photo and video I take?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the Dropbox app on your device
2. Open the overflow menu (three vertical dots) and choose "Settings"
3. Under "CAMERA UPLOAD" tap "Turn off Camera Upload"

If you've installed Dropbox's [Carousel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.carousel) app, it takes over the upload of photos.

1. Open the Carousel app
2. Click the weird smiley face in the upper left; this opens the "Settings" menu
3. Uncheck "Backup photos & videos" (or you can log out or uninstall the app)