# Stop android from automatically uploading images to dropbox and facebook

Tags: sync, facebook, dropbox, lg-optimus-2x, lg-optimus-l5

My wife has an Optimus LG. Every photo she takes automatically syncs with Dropbox and Facebook. I have looked but I can't see a way to stop this.

How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

For Dropbox, see [How do I configure Dropbox in my Galaxy S III so that it does NOT automatically upload every photo/video I take?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43718/how-do-i-configure-dropbox-in-my-galaxy-s-iii-so-that-it-does-not-automatically?rq=1)

For Facebook, see [How can I disable automatic Facebook photo sync?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51386/how-can-i-disable-automatic-facebook-photo-sync?rq=1)

Of course, you can also just uninstall (or disable) either app to stop it uploading pictures.

Comment: Yeah, I guess we'll try to uninstall the apps and reinstall them. Both solutions have already been done according to my wife and I just confirmed that those settings are set to not sync.